# Laravel 5.1 protecting routes with ownership using middleware

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.1, middleware

I'm trying to learn Laravel, but don't quite understand how i can accomplish my task the best way.

Scenario,

A user (user_id 5) may create a todo list, with the id of 3 (todo_id 3). Each of them live in their own model, so users model, and todo model. I'm currently checking if they created the todo by passing this into the method,

```
public function show($id)
{
    TodoList::where('id',$id)->where('user_id', auth::id())->firstOrFail();
    return 'ok';
}
```

So, i was thinking it would be possible to filter all this, using middleware. I have more models that requires the same action, so user 2, can't change/edit the todo_list for user 5 etc. And this needs to be attached to all methods, to block their access. Show, View, Delete etc.

Is there any way of doing this, so i don't have to create a new middleware for each model?

Answer (score 0):

Laravel Eloquent provides [`Query Scopes`](http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/eloquent#query-scopes) for you, this might be what you're looking for.

Your Model:

```
class TodoList extends Model {
    public function scopeFiltered($query, $id, $user_id)
    {
        return $query->where('id',$id)->where('user_id', $user_id);
    }
}
```

Calling:

```
TodoList::filtered($id, Auth::user()->id)
   ->get();
```

Comment: Yeah, it's kinda what I'm looking for. However, doing this, i would still need to do so for each model? Is there a more dynamic way of doing this? So i can specify the model name and get access to what i need?

You understand my issue, i just find it weird such common thing is "so hard" to accomplish.